Grabbing all *el7* packages from Ansible Package facts
We are doing an In-Place Upgrade from RHEL 7 to RHEL 8 in my organization and we've come to find out that not all RHEL 7 packages are removed after an OS Upgrade. I've been asked to report on all RHEL 7 packages leftover on the device. To start I've looked into Ansible Package facts which has a variable that looks something like:
'ansible_facts.packages:{
zlib: [
    {
        "arch": "x86_64",
        "epoch": null,
        "release": "11.el7",
        "source": "rpm",
        "version": "1.2.7"
    },
    {
        "arch": "x86_64",
        "epoch": null,
        "release": "10.el7",
        "source": "rpm",
        "version": "1.2.6"
    },
    {
        "arch": "x86_64",
        "epoch": null,
        "release": "10.el8",
        "source": "rpm",
        "version": "1.2.7"
    }
]
}
    

This occurs for a handful of packages, what I would like to do is to run a json_query against the entire dictionary of package_facts and determine what "el7" packages live on the host. That can tell me what I want to remove. Are there any suggestions on the json_query to run in order to find all packages that have an 'el7' in the release key?
Here's what I've tried so far:
vars:
  example_query1: "[?contains(release, 'el7')]"
  example_query2: "[?release == '*el7*']"
tasks:
  new_package_list: "{{ ansible_facts.packages | json_query(example_query) | list }}"


Not ansible but in my humble opinion easier. rpm -qa --qf "%{NAME}|%{VERSION}|%{RELEASE}|%{ARCH}\n"|grep "el7"

A quick (and dirty) variant with Ansible and Jinja2 filter techniques is as follows:
- name: Grab all packages with el7 releases
  set_fact:
    el7_packages: "{{ el7_packages | default({}) | combine(new_item | items2dict) }}"
  with_dict: "{{ ansible_facts.packages }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.key }}"
  vars:
    el7_releases: "{{ item.value | map(attribute='release') | select('search', 'el7') }}"
    new_item:
      - key: "{{ item.key }}"
        value: "{{ el7_releases }}"
  when: el7_releases | list | length

- name: Print found el7 packages
  debug:
    var: el7_packages


you iterate over each entry of the dict
with_dict: "{{ ansible_facts.packages }}"

you reduce the list of dicts to the release value and then filter the list by el7
el7_releases: "{{ item.value | map(attribute='release') | select('search', 'el7') }}"

only if a release with el7 exists, the package with its el7 releases is saved in the target dict el7_packages

Condition to ensure the list is not empty (means el7 release exists)
when: el7_releases | list | length
Add new_item to target dict
set_fact with el7_packages: "{{ el7_packages | default({}) | combine(new_item | items2dict) }}"


the result is a dict, the keys are the package names, the values are lists of release strings containing el7


Notes:

loop_control with label is only for cosmetics in the terminal
the new entry (new_item) is prepared as an array and converted into a dict via items2dict before combining

Result:
TASK [Grab all packages with el7 releases] *********************
ok: [localhost] => (item=zlib)
ok: [localhost] => (item=other_pkg)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=an_other_tool)

TASK [Print found el7 packages] ********************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "el7_packages": {
        "other_pkg": [
            "11.el7"
        ],
        "zlib": [
            "11.el7",
            "10.el7"
        ]
    }
}


Edit:
To get the whole dict as a result, instead of just the release string, only a minimal change of the variable assignment for el7_releases is required:
el7_releases: "{{ item.value | selectattr('release', 'search', 'el7') }}"
Code:
- name: Grab all packages with el7 releases
  set_fact:
    el7_packages: "{{ el7_packages | default({}) | combine(new_item | items2dict) }}"
  with_dict: "{{ ansible_facts.packages }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.key }}"
  vars:
    el7_releases: "{{ item.value | selectattr('release', 'search', 'el7') }}"
    new_item:
      - key: "{{ item.key }}"
        value: "{{ el7_releases }}"
  when: el7_releases | list | length

- name: Print found el7 packages
  debug:
    var: el7_packages

Reslut:
TASK [Grab all packages with el7 releases] ****************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=zlib)
ok: [localhost] => (item=other_pkg)
skipping: [localhost] => (item=an_other_tool)

TASK [Print found el7 packages] ***************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "el7_packages": {
        "other_pkg": [
            {
                "arch": "x86_64",
                "epoch": null,
                "release": "11.el7",
                "source": "rpm",
                "version": "1.2.7"
            }
        ],
        "zlib": [
            {
                "arch": "x86_64",
                "epoch": null,
                "release": "11.el7",
                "source": "rpm",
                "version": "1.2.7"
            },
            {
                "arch": "x86_64",
                "epoch": null,
                "release": "10.el7",
                "source": "rpm",
                "version": "1.2.6"
            }
        ]
    }
}


example input data:
packages:
  zlib:
    - arch: "x86_64"
      epoch: null
      release: "11.el7"
      source: "rpm"
      version: "1.2.7"

    - arch: "x86_64"
      epoch: null
      release: "10.el7"
      source: "rpm"
      version: "1.2.6"

    - arch: "x86_64"
      epoch: null
      release: "10.el8"
      source: "rpm"
      version: "1.2.7"

  other_pkg:
    - arch: "x86_64"
      epoch: null
      release: "11.el7"
      source: "rpm"
      version: "1.2.7"

    - arch: "x86_64"
      epoch: null
      release: "10.el8"
      source: "rpm"
      version: "1.2.7"

  an_other_tool:
    - arch: "x86_64"
      epoch: null
      release: "10.el8"
      source: "rpm"
      version: "1.2.7"


This is very close to what I need. But instead of just the package release information, what if I wanted the entire package information? Like the name, version, release, arch, etc. would something like that be possible for the RHEL 7 packages once they’re found?

As in the filter is the el7 in the release, but the capture I want is the entire package information.

@ZackMcCain I've added an Edit: section - with that small change you get the whole package information, instead of just the release string.

Q: "Instead of just the package release information, what if I wanted the entire package information? Like the name, version, release, arch, etc. would something like that be possible for the RHEL 7 packages once they’re found? ... As in the filter is the el7 in the release, but the capture I want is the entire package information."
Based on the already given good answer, a only slightly changed minimal example playbook
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - package_facts:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item.value }}"
    when: item.value | map(attribute='release') | select('search', redhat_release)
    with_dict: "{{ ansible_facts.packages }}"
    loop_control:
      label: "{{ item.key }}"
    vars:
      redhat_release: 'el9_2'

will output all 9.2 packages on a 9.5 system
TASK [debug] **********************
...
ok: [localhost] => (item=libcap) =>
  msg:
  - arch: x86_64
    epoch: null
    name: libcap
    release: 9.el9_2
    source: rpm
    version: '2.48'
...

In order to gain more performance one could focus next on combining these two
    when: item.value | map(attribute='release') | select('search', redhat_release)
    with_dict: "{{ ansible_facts.packages }}"

into one, generate a data structure before and instead of test when on list elements.
Similar Q&A

Is there anyway to extract a list with all packages which contain the string?


Just curios why does it output a skipping line for all packages that do not match the when conditional? skipping: [my_server] => (item=tcpdump) etc...

@Squashman, This is because Conditions based on registered variables, is skipped and skipped test. As well also one reason why one shoud dense down the data before processing it in general, specifically in a loop and generate a data structure before and instead of test when on list elements.

Get the keys, select the matching items in the lists, and create the dictionary
  pkg_el7_keys: "{{ ansible_facts.packages.keys() }}"
  pkg_el7_vals: "{{ ansible_facts.packages |
                    dict2items |
                    map(attribute='value') |
                    map('selectattr', 'release', 'regex', '^.*el7$') }}"
  pkg_el7_dict: "{{ dict(pkg_el7_keys | zip(pkg_el7_vals)) }}"

gives
  pkg_el7_dict:
    zlib:
    - {arch: x86_64, epoch: null, release: 11.el7, source: rpm, version: 1.2.7}
    - {arch: x86_64, epoch: null, release: 10.el7, source: rpm, version: 1.2.6}



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    ansible_facts:
      packages:
        zlib:
        - {arch: x86_64, epoch: null, release: 11.el7, source: rpm, version: 1.2.7}
        - {arch: x86_64, epoch: null, release: 10.el7, source: rpm, version: 1.2.6}
        - {arch: x86_64, epoch: null, release: 10.el8, source: rpm, version: 1.2.7}

    pkg_el7_keys: "{{ ansible_facts.packages.keys() }}"
    pkg_el7_vals: "{{ ansible_facts.packages |
                      dict2items |
                      map(attribute='value') |
                      map('selectattr', 'release', 'regex', '^.*el7$') }}"
    pkg_el7_dict: "{{ dict(pkg_el7_keys | zip(pkg_el7_vals)) }}"
                                               
        
  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: pkg_el7_dict | to_yaml


